# Verify $\tau=\{A \subseteq \mathbb{R}| |\mathbb{R}\setminus A| \leq |\mathbb{N}| \}$ is a topology

Tags: general-topology

Consider the set $\tau=\{A \subseteq \mathbb{R}| |\mathbb{R}\setminus A| \leq |\mathbb{N}|  \}$

Verify it is a topology

1. obviously $\mathbb{R} \in \tau$  since $ |\mathbb{R}\setminus \mathbb{R}|=0 \leq |\mathbb{N}|  \}$

but $\emptyset\notin \tau$ ? because $ |\mathbb{R}\setminus \emptyset|=|\mathbb{R}|  \leq |\mathbb{N}|  \}$ is false.... **(1) this is a problem, Should I assume $\emptyset$ is there anyway?**

2. Let $A_\alpha \in \tau$  $  \forall \alpha \in I$ $\implies$ $ |\mathbb{R}\setminus A_\alpha|  \leq |\mathbb{N}| $  $\forall \alpha$ now let $U=\bigcup_{\alpha \in I}A_\alpha$

$| \mathbb{R}\setminus\bigcup_{\alpha \in I}A_\alpha|=| \bigcap_{\alpha \in I} \mathbb{R}\setminus A_\alpha| $

**...(2) Now here is where I am unsure how can I justify this cardinality is $\leq |\mathbb{N}| $, what theorem should I invoque?**

3. Let $A_\alpha \in \tau$  $  \forall \alpha =1,...,m$ $\implies$ $ |\mathbb{R}\setminus A_\alpha|  \leq |\mathbb{N}| $  $\forall \alpha$ now let $B=\bigcap_{\alpha=1}^mA_\alpha$

$| \mathbb{R}\setminus\bigcap_{\alpha=1}^mA_\alpha|=|\bigcup_{\alpha=1}^m \mathbb{R}\setminus A_\alpha| $

**...(3) Same  here , how can I justify this cardinality is $\leq |\mathbb{N}| $, what theorem should I invoque?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you’ve noticed, $\tau$ is not actually a topology, since it fails to include the empty set. While this *may* be a trick question, I suspect that the omission is actually an oversight. I would point out that $\varnothing\notin\tau$, so that in fact $\tau$ is not a topology, but I would go on to prove that $\tau\cup\{\varnothing\}$ **is** a topology.

For your second question, pick any $\alpha_0\in I$ and observe that

$$\bigcap_{\alpha\in I}(\Bbb R\setminus A_\alpha)\subseteq\Bbb R\setminus A_{\alpha_0}\;,$$

so that automatically

$$\left|\bigcap_{\alpha\in I}(\Bbb R\setminus A_\alpha)\right|\le|\Bbb R\setminus A_{\alpha_0}|\;.$$

Finally, for the third question, what do you know about the union of a finite number of countable sets?

Comment: I know it is finite, I was just  looking for some theorem to back me up

Comment: @J.C.VegaO: No, it need not be finite. Think a minute: what if it’s just one set, and that set has the same cardinality as $\Bbb N$? It need not be finite, but it **is** ... what? (By the way, the usual name for this topology is the *co-countable topology*.)

Comment: I rushed it, I meant it is countable, so at most it has the cardinality of the naturals, since I haven't proved I was looking for a justification

Comment: @J.C.VegaO: Okay. I really don’t think that in a topology course you should at this point have to cite anything for the very basic result that the union of countably many countable sets is countable.